# How can I format my drive to have multiple partitions?

Tags: partitioning

Can I make a Home partition on my drive and move my home folder there without reformatting my entire disk?

I am booting my system off a USB stick and running Gparted. I can change the size of the partition and add another but I don't know how to set the file structure to recognize it as Home.

Answer (score 2):

Create the new partition and write the changes to disk. Note the device that is associated with the partition: it will be something like /dev/sda5.

Fire up a terminal, then execute:

```
ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid/
```

Locate the device that you created. The output will look like this:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 2010-10-10 12:00 35746711-2b3a-44bd-b75e-e9782243dbce -> ../../sda5
```

You need the device's UUID - in my case, that is 35746711-2b3a-44bd-b75e-e9782243dbce. Take note of this value.

Then, mount the root partition (using normal Gnome/KDE/similar interface) and edit the file named /etc/fstab inside that partition. The command is:

```
sudo gedit /media/YOUR_PARTITION/etc/fstab
```

To edit that file and copy your old files, follow the instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5484/how-can-i-move-my-home-directory-to-another-partition-if-its-already-part-of-th/5488#5488). You will need to change the UUID and the filesystem type, of course, from what is in that post.

Answer (score 1):

Since you need boot files and home to be in their own partitions, you need a total of 3 partitions. As you state in your question, resize existing partitions and create 3 new ones. The boot partition need only be 50 MB.

When the installer ask you for partitioning, simple select these empty partitions and set the mount point as follows

- 1 for boot and select mount point as **/boot** | size: 50mb
- 1 for home and select mount point as **/home**
  and
- 1 for root with mount point as **/**

You could always transfer the contents of your /home directory to the newly created partition and then install ubuntu mounting the partition as /home. See [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/5484/270) for details.

Answer (score 0):

The term you are looking for is "mount point". Set one mount point to / and one to /home and you're set. Find more about partitioning on the [Ubuntu help pages](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning%20issues?action=show&redirect=Partitioning).