# How can I move my /home directory to another partition if it's already part of the / partition?

Tags: partitioning, home-directory

I have a wonderful running Maverick Meerkat install going on right now. I want to move my `/home` to another partition as per many suggestions.

How can I go about doing this without reinstalling the entire Ubuntu system? Can I simply create the partition with `gparted` and then change the mount point of `/home` in fstab to reflect it or is it a bit more difficult?

Comment: I think it's best to follow the [Ubuntu wiki guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving). I used it a while ago and it worked just fine.

Comment: I like how that guide shows you how to find the GUID of your disks.  I didn't know how to do that until now.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, it is only a matter of adding a new entry to `/etc/fstab` and then copying the files over.

I suggest using UUIDs for the partition identifier in `fstab`, the syntax similar to this:

```
UUID=abcdabcd-acbd-abcd-abcd-abcdabcd /home ext4 defaults 0 2
```

Copying is best done as root, with the `-a` flag passed to `cp`. Also, better play safe and not remove the files immediately:

```
cp -a /home/* /path/to/new/partition/
mv /home /old_home
mkdir /home
```

Note that the user directories must be straight inside the partition, not in `/partition/home/`.

Comment: I make change in /etc/fstab but don't know how copy the files in /home to new partition /home becouse I have only one physicali disk with 4 partitions. "boot", "/ ", "/home" and "swap". Where can I create the nev /home that one is still there.

I need remove whole partiton "/home" on sdb2 and move it to sdb1 "/" After I restart PC I can see my root account but password didn't work. Now I can reinstal whole ubuntu again :(

Comment: But I olny need to resize partition using GParted but it did't work, first I must delete last "SWAP" partition than I can resizing partition before it which was mounted as "/home" but I able resize only up not down (I need to make partition smaller)

Comment: "I suggest using UUIDs for the partition identifier in fstab" is not clear; What command is "the partition identifier", and how is it used to retrieve UUID?

Comment: rsync might be better for copying the files as it can preserve ownership and permissions, and isn't confused by wonky filenames. e.g. `rsync -rpov ~/ /media/newHomePartition` also it's waaaay faster

Answer (score 1):

Are you planning on sharing your /home with windows? If so, I made a few mistakes but it is do-able. Read my learning curve [here.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/83172/repairing-the-fstab)

Also, How-To Geek has a good tutorial on merging linux and windows /home and My Documents [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/35807/how-to-harmonize-your-dual-boot-setup-for-windows-and-ubuntu/) as well as many others (HTG is my other source of invaluable info!)

Answer (score 1):

**Special Case: Copy home directory to Portable USB drive**

There are some good reasons to copy your home directory to a USB drive. Not having to leave home at home when traveling is one. Not trusting your room mate is another.

- Format flash drive to ext4.
- As root, use **Grsync** to copy `/home/{username}` from the internal drive to the flash drive. Preserving owner, permissions and group works for me.

  [image: Grsync window]
- Copy the UUID of the new partition.
- Edit `/etc/fstab` on the internal drive to add the `/home` UUID:

  ```
  UUID={UUID from above} /home   ext4    defaults        0       0
  ```

**Notes:**

- It might be a good idea to use an encrypted home when traveling.
- If USB home permissions get messed up, they can be updated from the internal drive.
- You will either need the USB to boot the computer or edit the USB's home `fstab` entry with an `#` in front of it.

Thanks to [ubfan1](https://askubuntu.com/users/82196/ubfan1) for the hint: [Using existing home directory from a bootable external drive](https://askubuntu.com/a/991296/618353)