# Increasing ubuntu partition space

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, gparted

I have a laptop configured with dual boot (Ubuntu and win7). Partition in which Ubuntu in installed is running out of space(alloted only 15 GB space earlier).I want to use one of my empty partition for Ubuntu. As far as I know I think I have two option to do that to increase the Ubuntu partition size first is to merg that free partition using gparted into it, but that will take lots of time since that free partition is located to the left of Ubuntu partition (comes before on disk addressing space) so gparted will have to shift whole 15 GB of existing data in Ubuntu partition towards left. Other option is to export one of my root director like /usr(or other that consumes lots of space) to that partition.

So, I have following questions:

1. Which option is safe, efficient and comfortable.
2. If I were to export one of root dir(like /usr ) which one should I export and HOW. I think /usr should be the one since user programs are installed in it which constitute major portion of space.
3. Any other better way of doing this??

Answer (score 1):

You should move your /home directory to the other partition.  See [How can I move my /home directory to another partition if it's already part of the / partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5484/how-can-i-move-my-home-directory-to-another-partition-if-its-already-part-of-th).