# Problem mounting Drive

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I asked this  [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37580/increasing-ubuntu-partition-space) earlier. I opted for mearging the Ubuntu partition with the  free partition, since I was not sure with the size for /home. Thing went bad GRUB got corrupted, may be because Ubuntu partition UUID was changed due to partition deletion. After googling for some time I got that problem fixed using [this](http://www.daniweb.com/community-center/it-professionals-lounge/threads/85926/417880#post417880) post but now I am not able to view my win7 partition in linux.

Here is my Partition table configuration(from gpartd):

[image]

Now when I try to mount win7  drive I get following error:

> Error mounting: mount exited with exit code 1: helper failed with:
>   mount: according to mtab, /dev/sda5 is already mounted on /
>   mount failed

Another problem that I am at loss of 3GB of space on sda5 (ubuntu) partition. gparted is showing its a 35 GB partition but Disk utility shows its a 38 GB partition as shown bellow:
[image]
Why is it so.How do I recover it.

**EDIT:**

Contents of /etc/fstab:
[image]

Comment: Would you mind putting up a print out of /etc/fstab? The `GParted` graphic above says that the mount points for both Ubuntu and Win7 are /. You can't mount them both there simultaneously, but you could mount Win7 at, say, /Win7.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can fix it with [Mount-Manager](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/mountmanager).
But first backup your fstab (`sudo cp /etc/fstab /etc/fstab.bak`).

You have not lost 3GB, this is how each software interpret the space of the disk. Look at your others partitions, all are "smaller" at GParted.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right concerning the 'loss' of space issue. It's frustrating that things aren't standardized but that's how it works unfortunately.