# cdrom listed in mtab but not in fstab?

Tags: apt, synaptic, fstab

my problem is that the cdrom is listed properly in /etc/mtab file but not in /etc/fstab file.

mtab contents:

```
/dev/sda1 / ext4 rw,errors=remount-ro,commit=0 0 0
proc /proc proc rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev 0 0
none /sys sysfs rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev 0 0
fusectl /sys/fs/fuse/connections fusectl rw 0 0
none /sys/kernel/debug debugfs rw 0 0
none /sys/kernel/security securityfs rw 0 0
none /dev devtmpfs rw,mode=0755 0 0
none /dev/pts devpts rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620 0 0
none /dev/shm tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev 0 0
none /var/run tmpfs rw,nosuid,mode=0755 0 0
none /var/lock tmpfs rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev 0 0
binfmt_misc /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc binfmt_misc rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev 0 0
gvfs-fuse-daemon /home/ryan/.gvfs fuse.gvfs-fuse-daemon rw,nosuid,nodev,user=ryan 0 0
/dev/sr0 /media/Kubuntu\04011.10\040i386 iso9660 ro,nosuid,nodev,uhelper=udisks,uid=1000,gid=1000,iocharset=utf8,mode=0400,dmode=0500 0 0
/etc/mtab (END)
```

fstab contents:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid -o value -s UUID' to print the universally unique identifier
# for a device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name
# devices that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=c72c38c5-9b1b-4ae6-bafb-860988a3bcae /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       0
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=25639380-c36f-491f-912d-a01477bf0a5c none            swap    sw              0       0
```

see..no cdrom in fstab. Actual problem was that I wasn't able to use cdrom as a source from synaptic...searched..found out about apt-cdrom...used...got unable to mount error...again searched...found out that apt-get uses sources listed in /etc/apt/sources.list and to add a cdrom to this list ,it must be in fstab....again searched..until now the conclusion is that I have to maually add cdrom to fstab.I'll be using [this as help](https://askubuntu.com/questions/83172/repairing-the-fstab).

But isn't this a problem...manually fixing an important system file..why debian/mint guys are not fixing it?????

System snapshots are from linux mint 11 but I have similar issues with Kubuntu 11.10 both are running as guests using virtual box on windows 7(seeee a linux newbie)

Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mtab` is what's currently mounted. `fstab` is the list of things to mount at boot, and some static mount points for mounting by hand.

You can easily add a cdrom mount point (it looks like apt-cdrom needs one):

```
/dev/scd0       /media/cdrom0   udf,iso9660 user,noauto     0       0
```

Comment: wow...wait "static mount points"...what is it and how I create one..thanks

Comment: By editing `fstab`. Everything listed in `fstab` is mounted at boot, unless there's a `noauto` option. Then it can still be easy mounted, as all the details are in `fstab`. With the example I give above, it can be mounted by just typing `mount /dev/cdrom0`. All the details will come from `fstab`.