# Stuck at boot screen: checking file system stage

Tags: mount, boot-failure

I cant login to Ubuntu.

The splash screen stuck after checking file system. I used "storage device manager" (pySdm) to mount drives at boot time  and also changed some options in it (which I can't remember now).

Since then Ubuntu (12.04) is not starting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your problem is the the new drives you added, maybe you can boot into root, you can see this question [How do I boot into a root shell?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92556/how-do-i-boot-into-a-root-shell) , edit `/etc/fstab` and check if there is anything wrong with the new disks.

If you don't find anything wrong, create a backup of the file (to be safe) and remove the new added disks entries, just make sure not to remove your Ubuntu partitions.

If you don't find anything wrong, try posting the contents of the file here maybe you can get some help with it.

Hope this helps

Comment: i'm completely newbee and i cant open fstab in shell prompt. @jON45

Comment: Did you manage to do the step and fall into a root shell? If your problem is the editor you can use pico to edit the file. just do "pico /etc/fstab" (don't forget to create a backup of the file "cp /etc/fstab /etc/fstab.backup")

Comment: i got fstab.pls hlp me with bcpping the file.

Comment: error writing /etc/fstab.backup: read-only file system @jON45

Comment: just do this "mount -n -o remount / " and it should be read write

Comment: # /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>   <options>    <dump>    <pass>
proc    /proc    proc        nodev,noexec,nosuid    0   0
entry for /dev/sda3 :
uuid=917d1cad-a914-47ee-a9e2-4e3d2025285a    /ext2 errors=remount-ro,user    0   1

Comment: Please remove the "entry for" text, and give a space here "/ ext2". Save, close, and run "sudo mount -a" to check for errors.  If any error, please post it here, don't reboot your computer if there was any error.

Comment: i got permission denied error and then matrix like screen
/usr/bin/gettext.sh: line 90:
/usr/bin/envsubst : permission denied.

Comment: can you please try and remove the "/dev/sda3 :" and just keep the "uuid=917d1cad-a914-47ee-a9e2-4e3d2025285a / ext2 errors=remount-ro,user 0 1" and run "mount -a"?

Comment: once again redo the activities frm begin.
mount -n -o remount /
pico /etc/fstab
bash: /usr/bin/pico: permission denied

Comment: And you are in a root shell? Do you see some thing like this root@... ?

Comment: root@DELL-PC:~#

Comment: it's strange you don't have permission to access the fstab being root. I'm sorry but I can't help you without seeing it, I would be just guessing. Please copy the backup back to file "cp /etc/fstab.backup /etc/fstab".

Comment: i am not able to backup the file because of read only file systém even after "mount -n -o remount /"

Comment: is there any alternativě way to get write permissions?

Comment: you can add full read write permissions to the file by doing "chmod 0666 /etc/fstab" this is the command that changes the permissions in linux and unix

Comment: i got crazy again read only file system. afraid that my disk is failing.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to jON45 for his time. I've fixed fstab by logging as live user and editing fstab.
 the code used to login are here

```
sudo mkdir /media/mount<br>
sudo mount /dev/sd__ /media/mount<br>
sudo vi /media/mount/etc/fstab<br>
```

i must say that im a hero/computer geek in school. thanks to Jnlopes.
webs to fix fstab,

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab?

[Repairing the FSTAB](https://askubuntu.com/questions/83172/repairing-the-fstab)

Comment: You can just do as the answer in here, https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/44033/14720v, says. Probably no need for Live CD.