# ubuntu 16.04 gparted resize root boot fails

Tags: 16.04, boot, fdisk, boot-partition

I was running out of disk space on root for ubuntu 16.04.  I used gparted to resize it.  It seemed to go okay (no error messages).  gparted showed everything okay.  On boot, I get my grub menu okay but when it goes to boot it says "cleaning /dev/sda1" or something like that and hangs there.  I go back to gparted and it won't select the sda1 partition.  The first partition it'll select is the sda5 (home partition).  I used live-usb to boot ubuntu and looked at fstab. For sda1, it says errors=remount-ro.

How do I fix this using live-usb?  Or should I just re-install ubuntu from scratch?  I don't think it's a grub problem because the grub menu shows okay - but maybe it is.

I run fdisk -l and it shows all partitions but the ID for sda1 is the same as sda5 which doesn't seem right.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the answer using these 2 prior posts: 
[Repairing broken installation from Live USB without losing data](https://askubuntu.com/questions/726071/repairing-broken-installation-from-live-usb-without-losing-data)

[Repairing the FSTAB](https://askubuntu.com/questions/83172/repairing-the-fstab)

The edit needed in fstab was to remove reference to the partition that I had deleted so I could increase size of root.  Hopefully no more problems.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is too later, but this is to help others who are searching for answers. Run a live ubuntu on usb and then you can open Disks app to resize your boot drive. Since this is the only moment the root partition is not used by your machine.