# How can I setup my SSD+HDD-setup the best way?

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, ssd

I have recently build a new system with a 256GB SSD and a 3TB HDD. I want to save all my files on my HDD while my programs and Ubuntu 14.04 should run on my SSD to boost the performance.
I might also be installing a Windows version later, but I am not so sure about that...

How can I do that? Is it possible to do that without reinstalling Ubuntu?

**edit:**

When I installed Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit on my system I chose Ubuntu to get installed on my SSD with the auto-partitioner. 
I have not yet copied my data from my ext. hard drive to my internal storage, as I want it to go to the HDD, while all my installs should go to my SSD.
Later I might want another SSD-partition for Windows (if I install it) to use as my oprating system for gaming.

Comment: Please include more details: what partitions you currently have on both drives? By asking "Is it possible to do it without reinstalling Ubuntu?" do you mean after Windows installation or you have already installed Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

If you have already installed Ubuntu on SSD then after Windows installation you will need to run Boot Repair. The steps you take are described here:

[How to install the Boot-Repair tool in an Ubuntu live disc?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/226061/how-to-install-the-boot-repair-tool-in-an-ubuntu-live-disc)

If you already have Ubuntu on HDD, so I would recommend just to remorarily save your `/home` folder to another partition, then manage your partitions (maybe you want to delete the previous one which contained Ubuntu)  with [Gparted](http://gparted.org/), which is included in Ubuntu and Live CD. The thread below has explanations how to manage partitions with Gparted.

[How to resize partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions)

During the installation you could create or choose a partition for your `/home` folder, so you could place `home` on HDD having the `/` on SSD.

If you have already installed Ubuntu and want to move your *home* partition from SSD to HDD rather than reinstall Ubuntiu, then have a look at this thread:

[How can I move my /home directory to another partition if it's already part of the / partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5484/how-can-i-move-my-home-directory-to-another-partition-if-its-already-part-of-t)

Comment: In installation stage I chose ubuntu to get installed on my ssd and then let the auto-partitioner do the rest. Now I just want to move my home folder to my hdd so I wont block space on my ssd. I might look into installing Windows as my second operating system in one or to month, but I would only use it for gaming so I would just run it of my SSD.

Comment: I added some additional answer about `/home` folder to the answer.