# "remap" (probably wrong word) my /opt folder?

Tags: directory, directory-structure

Long ago when I setup my Linux server, I installed the OS on a rather small SSD having intended on keeping all the large data on NAS drives.

I didn't realize  my /opt folder would get so large.  It is on the small SSD.

Is there a simple way for me to "remap" that folder so that i don't have to go make any changes in programs that may reference it, but so that it is now physically residing on my larger drive?

Sorry if this is a dumb Q.  I know a very narrow scope regarding Ubuntu :)

Comment: You can move the contents to a separate device and *mount* it at `/opt`, or use a symbolic link as described here [Move /opt to a different, already existing drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/900496/move-opt-to-a-different-already-existing-drive) or a *bind mount*

Comment: I would learn toward keeping /opt on the SSD with symbolic links for your applications to another drive using `ln` That way you can have some applications as part of the system and others that might not be there if the NAS is out.