# How to move home directory to a new partition? And does it delete files?

Tags: partitioning

I would like to move my `/home/[user]` to my partitioned drive that is currently `/media/[user]/D`.

I have been saving all of my pertinent files on the second drive, but I would like to make it a shorter path like `~`.

Comment: There is a good guide at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving

Answer (score 0):

If you want to move the whole `/home` to a another partition (change `/home` partition) as muru already said the workaround is [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5484/how-can-i-move-my-home-directory-to-another-partition-if-its-already-part-of-t).

However if you want to only change a specific user home directory:

```
sudo usermod -d /media/user/d uesername
```

- -d : sets `/media/user/d` as new home directory for selected user.

And it does not remove your files from: `/media/user/d`.