# steam after moved home

Tags: steam, 17.04, zfs

I set up a ZFS tank (from root busybox) :

```
mv /home /home-old
zs create -omountpoint=/home/ tank/home
rsync -arv --progress /home-old /home
```

now when i try to run steam I get :

```
t@ts:~$ steam
ILocalize::AddFile() failed to load file "public/steambootstrapper_english.txt".
[2017-05-30 19:09:30] Startup - updater built Nov 23 2016 01:05:42
[2017-05-30 19:09:30] Verifying installation...
[2017-05-30 19:09:30] Unable to read and verify install manifest /home/t/.steam/package/steam_client_ubuntu12.installed
[2017-05-30 19:09:30] Verification complete
[2017-05-30 19:09:30] Downloading Update...
../tier1/fileio.cpp (3186) : Assertion Failed: Failed to determine free disk space for ., error 75
[2017-05-30 19:09:30] Error: Steam needs at least 250MB of free disk space to update.
[2017-05-30 19:09:30] Error: Steam needs to be online to update.     Please confirm your network connection and try again.
[2017-05-30 19:09:52] Shutdown
threadtools.cpp (3283) : Assertion Failed: Illegal termination of worker thread 'Thread(0x0x576b3530/0x0xefd7db'
cat: '/home/t/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime.tar.xz.part*': No such file or directory
tar: This does not look like a tar archive
xz: (stdin): File format not recognized
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
find: ‘/home/t/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime’: No such file or directory
t@ts:~$
```

[image]

every other app works fine.

Comment: i tried this guide https://askubuntu.com/a/5488/307184 in hopes to skip around the real issue here but of course even logged out as root busybox I couldn't rename home as it is in use by the zfs mount point. but really it leads us back to this whole nonsensical thing. I have 3 terabytes of free space thanks to the ZFS mount on home. I really shouldn't be getting a "lack of space" error.