# How do I move my Home directory onto a USB EXT4 drive (18.04)

Tags: boot, usb, home-directory

Following a **default minimal installation** of 18.04, I now want to **move** my `/home` directory **to** an `EXT4` formatted **USB flash drive**.

By default in 18.04 the `/home` directory is mounted as part of the `/` partition.

Is there a clean and safe way to move/reconfigure my `/home` directory to the USB flash drive, or would it be cleaner/safer to reinstall Ubuntu and configure the `/home` directory on USB during the install process? Or, is having your `/home` folder on a separate USB drive ill-advised?

I've looked at many similar questions/answers, but can't find a contemporary clean and clear solution.

Comment: Don't. Just don't. Just use the normal tools to move your --directories-- to the USB. See `~./config/users-dirs.dirs`. Leave home on a fixed disk. If the USB ever errors out and does not mount you are screwed: and need to fix the problem outside your installation :P

Comment: @Rizwind I appreciate your candor, tx

Comment: By the way, there is no directory named `Home` in a regular Linux installation. You may be thinking of `/home`.

Comment: mkusb now has an easy to use option for backing up home directories on a persistent flash drive. I generally use grsync, (GUI rsync), for copying home directory. After you can edit /etc/fstab to add the UUID of the new home partition. The guide timanix shows is good. See also https://askubuntu.com/questions/991189/using-existing-home-directory-from-a-bootable-external-drive

Answer (score 1):

**Copy home to Portable USB drive**

Format flash drive to ext4.

As root use Grsync to copy home/{username} from internal drive to the flash drive. Preserving owner, permissions and group works for me.

[image]

Copy or write down UUID of the new partition.

Edit /etc/fstab on the internal drive to add the /home UUID:

```
UUID={UUID from above} /home   ext4    defaults        0       0
```

It might be a good idea to use an encrypted home when traveling.

Thanks to ubfan1 for hint

Comment: You can delete the answer for now, and undelete it when ready.

Comment: In the past I have spent days making an answer just to have the thread closed before I could post it. I prefer to reserve a spot if I see :"possible duplicate" in the comments.

Comment: @C.S.Cameron For the future, if this is not a full complete answer, then you should not post it as an answer just to "reserve a spot".  That's not how the system works.

Comment: Thanks @ Thomas Ward: Is there a way to post, delete and resurrect an answer? If I spend the time researching and writing and testing an answer I would like to know that I can publish it.

Comment: @C.S.Cameron That would be a good question for [Meta], I think.

Comment: Thanks a lot @wjandrea: I asked on Meta and have gotten at least one down vote so far, but I feel more coming.

Comment: The advice you gave as a comment on the question might be better incorporated into your answer. (Also, I'm slightly surprised, given that you were apparently keen to answer it, that I'm the first one to upvote the question ;) )

Comment: @Zanna: What part of the comment did I not use? At the time I was hoping to come up with a slightly more exciting answer. I guess there are just not that many people who need to carry home around on a pen drive. Maybe I should load a few screen shots.

Comment: I was thinking of the tantalising suggestion about `mkusb` :)

Comment: Why bother? Sudodus will probably just beat me to it. However you are right, dus home backup and restore makes it easy to back up home, create a home-rw persistent partition and upgrade persistent drives from one version to another.