# User Profile stored on USB Stick to login to any Ubuntu Device

Tags: 16.04, usb, 18.04, user-profile

Had an out of the box idea and wanted to run it by people with more experience to see if it was feasible.

I wondered if was possible to store an entire user profile on a USB Stick that could be used on any Ubuntu device.

The scenario, We have 5 laptops to use between a team of people so there is no guarantee that a user could always get the same laptop.

Proposed solution, The User Profile is stored on a USB Stick that the user would plugin to the laptop when the laptop is switched on it would then see this new user and allow the user to login where all their files would be accessible and their user sessions gnome keyring etc.

It may not be possible, just thought I'd throw it out there and see what others thought

Comment: My wife has her /home partition on an external drive. Her desktop uses her external home when it is plugged in. https://askubuntu.com/questions/991189/using-existing-home-directory-from-a-bootable-external-drive    I'm not sure how to do this with multiple users yet, good question.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Sorry i didn't repsond sooner. I spoke with some really helpful guys on the Ubuntu Discord channel who couldn't really think of a solution where the users password file is stored on a separate drive too. in the end we went with giving each user a Ubuntu Live USB with persistent storage.