# Need to change default boot order. Instead of Ubuntu 21.04 to Windows 7

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-7, 21.04

I have now three hard disks in my desktop. A Samsung SSD that boots Win7, a Toshiba HDD which is not bootable, and yesterday I added a Crucial SSD which boots Ubuntu 21.04.

If I now simply start my computer, Linux on the Crucial will boot..

If at startup I press <kbd>F11</kbd> this allows to choose between these three and surprisingly, a non-existing fourth named "Ubuntu"(?). If I click on the Samsung then Windows will boot, if I click on the Crucial (or Ubuntu) Ubuntu will boot. As you can see on the left of the two pictures:

[image: https://ibb.co/ctB75g0]

The right picture shows what I get when press <kbd>F2</kbd>, the boot order setting at the ASRock Motherboard, while booting, I only get to "choose" between the identical Crucial and Ubuntu...

I want the Samsung to boot Win7 as default. From what I have heard, I have to do this in Ubuntu, and I know absolutely nothing about it. How do I make this change?

It was suggested to use grub-customizer for this, but as the picture shows, it does not even see the Samsung disk with the Windows.

[image: https://ibb.co/fq1bKZC]

My Win7 is not an UEFI, it is a legacy installation. Could that be the reason?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217904/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-how-to-fix)

Comment: I am NOT unable to boot into Windows, I want it to be the default...

Comment: Your Win7 is legacy, your Ubuntu is UEFI. You will not be able to  boot them both from a single grub menu. Your simplest solution is to reinstall Ubuntu in Legacy mode.

Comment: Thank you, that is what I thought too, but of course I have no idea how to do that. I can boot both from the normal BIOS of my ASRock motherboard, and it ...... me off, that Ubuntu simply overrides settings on my computer without asking! Arer there instructions for this, that are understandable for some new to Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert an existing installation of Ubuntu from legacy to UEFI and vice versa.
You need to reinstall GRUB to the device hosting grub, in my case this is /dev/nvme0n1

Legacy to UEFI

```bsh
sudo grub-install --boot-directory=/boot --bootloader-id=ubuntu  --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/boot/efi  /dev/nvme0n1
```

UEFI to Legacy

```bsh
sudo grub-install --boot-directory=/boot --bootloader-id=ubuntu /dev/nvme0n1
```

Then update grub `sudo update-grub`

Now you can list grub entries by using this command:

```bsh
grep -E "^(menuentry|submenu)" /boot/grub/grub.cfg | cut -d"'" -f2 | nl -v0
```

In my case it will show the following

```
     0  Ubuntu
     1  Advanced Options for Ubuntu
     2  Windows Boot Manager (sur /dev/nvme1n1p2)
     3  UEFI Firmware Settings
```

After you have to edit `/etc/default/grub` and set the corresponding number  to `GRUB_DEFAULT=0`.

In my case Windows is entry n°2 so it will be `GRUB_DEFAULT=2`

Then you have to use `sudo update-grub` to update your grub, and now your computer will always boot windows by default.

Cheers

Comment: Thank You...  As far as I have understood PonJar's comment, I need to change the ubuntu installation from UEFI to legacy ??? You mention the other way around.... ?

Comment: I've edited my comment, you can change from legacy to uefi and vice versa.

Comment: UEFI drive should be partitioned as gpt, not older MBR. And with gpt you need a bios_grub partition 1MB unformatted with bios_grub flag for correct BIOS/CSM/Legacy install of grub (grub-pc). Or you need an ESP - efi system partition as FAT32 300 to 500MB with esp/boot flags for UEFI install of grub (grub-efi-amd64). When I was first converting drives to new UEFI install I added both bios_grub & ESP as first two partitions. I already had started using gpt with all BIOS installs on old system several years before.

Comment: Fractalyse....   What does:     "^(menuentry|submenu)"     mean in this line:grep -E "^(menuentry|submenu)" /boot/grub/grub.cfg | cut -d"'" -f2 | nl -v0   As I wrote, I am new to Linux and I did not know that installing ubuntu would upset the other half of my computer and not mention windows in its boot options...

Comment: It's a bash command, that shows you the entries of grub menu. If you are not familiar with Linux and terminal commands, the simplest way for you is to reinstall Ubuntu in legacy mode by disabling UEFI in your BIOS.

Comment: I went through the uefi setup of my ASRock B85m motherboard and found many settings but none that would allow to change it to legacy for an installation on a second SSD....?

Comment: I guess this is called "CSM" for "Compatibility Support Module", Here is the manual :  https://download.asrock.com/Manual/B85M.pdf search for "CSM" in manual there is the procedure

Comment: Fractalyse....    All I did was getting a second SSD to install ubuntu next to Win in my computer, to see how it works for me. And as in all the numerous previous attempts in the past 18 years, Linux makes a mess of things, by doing things no one asked it to do. This time, grub simply imposes itself over all booting, and as many times before I wasted many hours trying to stop Linux from messing with the rest my system. I do not have time for this kind of effort.

Comment: So thank you very much for trying, but I am sick and tired of spending hours on fixing things, that used to work just fine.
I will simply unplug the power supply for that SSD, until I want to actually use ubuntu, or until I decide to simply wipe it and use it as another storage for windows.
Thank you, I apologize for having wasted your time...

Answer (score 0):

I've searched similar solution recently and this is the best I've found

[boot loader configure last saved in ubuntu terminal](https://askubuntu.com/a/1104700/1672257)

So according to this answer you can change the boot loader to load the last os you opened!
also if you're not comfortable with gedit you can select for nano editor. [This video shows to do with nano editor](https://youtu.be/IbCaGfwT0yo) in very precise explaination.