# Ubuntu / Windows Dual Boot with seperate partition for Desktop, Documents etc

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I have set up an Ubuntu 20.04 / Windows 10 Dual Boot with all the partitions the OS need. Additionally, I have created a shared NTFS partition called "Data", where I want my Desktop, Documents folder etc. to be located. For Windows this worked fine, but Ubuntu does not seem to get things right.

To relocate the specific folders to the Data partition, I have edited their path in the `/home/xy/.config/user-dirs.dirs` file to `/media/xy/Data/Desktop/` etc., but every time I log into Ubuntu, all the paths I changed are set to `$HOME/`.
All the `/media/...` paths do exist and I can access them from the terminal and from Nautilus.

Comment: Make sure Windows fast start up is off. Keep desktop in /home.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1271486/installing-ubuntu-on-ssd-and-setting-home-on-hdd You need to mount partition(s) with fstab. I use links and back with XP had both a NTFS partition for some shared data and ext4 for Linux data. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013677/storing-data-on-second-hdd-mounting & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058756/installing-all-applications-on-a-ssd-disk-and-putting-all-files-on-hdd-disk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of oldfred's comment I have now solved the problem.
Mainly, what I had to do was add an entry to the `fstab` file to mount the partition at `/mnt/data/`. I did not even have to create links in my home directory, editing the `user-dirs.dirs` file worked for me.