# How to extend ROM memory with USB stick / install apps on USB stick

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, usb, ram

I found thousands of tutorials on how to install Ubuntu on USB stick but I have got a different problem. I have created small 20 GB partition for Ubuntu on my SSD and because it has disrupted all my Windows 10 files - I had to install everything from the scratch - I do not have the possibility to extend it again without the risk of disrupting Windows. I would like to use 128GB USB stick as an extension for system, apps and temp files. I know I can put my files there but it is just a small amount of data, most of it is mounted into Ubuntu and as far as I know, I cannot choose where the system stores those files.
Does anybody have any idea how I can manage this situation now? Thank you for any help!!

Comment: What version of Ubuntu do you think corrupted your Windows system?

Comment: I don't think it was the Ubuntu fault, I made a new partition on free space of existing Win10 partition and as soon as I used the new one for installing Ubuntu, it has overwritten some files making them unusable on windows.. but it was Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

Comment: If you are going to install Ubuntu again I suggest to use the defaults that has never gone wrong for me. You install windows first do not make any partitions. Ubuntu during install will partition the drive suggesting half for each OS. Most new users get in trouble trying to be fancy with the install.

Comment: It would be helpful couple of weeks ago but now I don't want to install anything again, I have spent so much time trying to set it up and rescue the files on windows that now I only wish to have some more memory space using USB stick instead SSD..

Comment: Quite honestly I do not think that idea is going to work good luck.

Comment: My / (root) including /home is current 9.5GB. I regularly houseclean and moved all my data including some larger hidden folders in /home like Firefox & Thunderbird folders to a /mnt/data partition. Best not to use removable drives, but you can do this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013677/storing-data-on-second-hdd-mounting & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058756/installing-all-applications-on-a-ssd-disk-and-putting-all-files-on-hdd-disk For external devices, may also want to add the nofail option, so boot continues even when device isn't available. And flash drives have limited lives.

Comment: If adjusting or changing Windows partitions, it is best to do it with Window's tools/programs, do not use Ubuntu/Linux programs.  Thinking you might have used gparted or something from Ubuntu.  If wanting to a USB stick, would do a full install onto the stick instead of just part.

Comment: You can easily move your home to USB, 20GB on your SSD should be enough for your system. Here is what my wife did, See https://askubuntu.com/questions/991189/using-existing-home-directory-from-a-bootable-external-drive Windows will also let you move all or part of Documents and Settings to another drive.

Comment: Thank you for all the comments, I decided to move /home folder on the USB storage and I have more than 5GB now + all new data will be stored on the USB anyways. https://www.maketecheasier.com/move-home-folder-ubuntu/

Answer (score 0):

### Putting home directory on USB

You can easily move your home to USB, 20GB on your SSD should be enough for your system if you do not install too many programs.

Here is what my wife did, See [Using existing home directory from a bootable external drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/991189/using-existing-home-directory-from-a-bootable-external-drive).

I think Fabby answers your original question here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1139085/43926

Windows will also let you move all or part of Documents and Settings to another drive. Open C:\Users\ [UserName] and right click the folder you want to move, (say Documents or Downloads, etc), then select location. the rest will be obvious.