# How to install Ubuntu on ssd, but stored large data on HDD?

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, hard-drive, ssd

I'm newbie in a Linux world and have decided few days ago to try a Linux. The only one thing which i'm not sure about, how to participating both drivers correctly. So, ssd - /boot 1024mb, /swap 8gb, /root 80gb, /home the rest of the memory on ssd. Alright, after this step i have a doubt how to properly label HDD? Give it the entire storage space for /data? Or mount and format it separately as /mnt/home/myfiles after installation through Gparted or Gnome disk utility?

Comment: Advice for new users: Focus on making your first install *successful* rather than *perfect*. Many new users misjudge the partition sizes they need for their usage, and wind up re-partitioning after a few months. So don't worry much about partitioning the first time -- simply try the Ubuntu default settings. Once you have experience with a successful install, you can re-partition (or reinstall) to customize the more complex system you have in mind.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I move my /home directory to another partition if it's already part of the / partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5484/how-can-i-move-my-home-directory-to-another-partition-if-its-already-part-of-t)

Comment: If UEFI install you want an ESP - efi system partition and do not need a /boot partition. I agree that a new user is better starting with defaults and then after some experience defining sizes. Some examples on data on HDD. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013677/storing-data-on-second-hdd-mounting & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058756/installing-all-applications-on-a-ssd-disk-and-putting-all-files-on-hdd-disk I like to have several / (root) partitions on SSD, so each new LTS can be in a separate partition.

Answer (score 0):

It's your data, so it's just a matter of how do you want to organize it. There is no rule.

Myself I would probably make a single partition on the entire HDD and mount it as `/data`. Actually, I have a similar setup (SSD+HDD) and have placed the entire `/home` directory on HDD, while rest of the system is on the SSD. But it depends entirely on how do you want it organized.

Comment: The all what I actually want is run system and programs as browser, krita and etc from ssd, but keep files as documents, videos, photos on HDD To reduce rewriting cycles of ssd. So if you'll give me a tip how to better participating them both, I'd be really glad

Comment: @AlexanderSusaninov That was my point as well and that is the reason why I put my entire `/home` on HDD. If you want to avoid rewriting SSD it is reasonable to put swap partition on HDD as well. The swap will be slower, but it will not rewrite SSD. So give your entire SSD to the system (I don't even use separate partitions; have one main partition on SSD for everything) and use HDD for swap partition and `/home`.